# React.js splice removing wrong item from array list

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-dom

I want to remove an item from an array getting the target.id, this app  is for a cart, so in other words i want to remove an item from the cart when i click on the bin icon.

```
<span style={{fontSize:'50px'}}>Basket</span>
    <ul style={{listStyle: 'none'}}>
      {this.state.clickedNum.map((i) => <li key = 
      {this.props.gameData.id[i]} value={i}>
          {this.props.gameData.gameNames[i]} <br/>
          <img src={require('../assets/coins.png')} style={{width:'20px'}}/> 
          <strong> {this.props.gameData.prices[i]} Gil </strong>
          <img src={require('../assets/bin.png')} style={{width:'20px', justifyContent:' flex-end'}} id={this.props.gameData.id[i]}  onClick={this.removeClick}/>
          <br/>
          <hr style={{borderColor:'black'}} />
       </li>
     </ul>
```

This is the onClick={this.removeClick} function:

```
removeClick = (e) => {
    e = e.target.id;
    let clickedNum = this.state.clickedNum;
    let isDisabled = this.state.isDisabled;
    console.log("this is i" + e);

    clickedNum.splice(e, 1);
    isDisabled.splice(e,1);


    this.setState({
        clickedNum: clickedNum,
        isDisabled:isDisabled
    })

    this.forceUpdate();

}
```

remove click is binded like this in the **constructor** function:

```
    this.removeClick = this.removeClick.bind(this);
```

The problem comes that if you click the bin when there is more than one item in the cart it does not delete the first element and it does not always delete the correct item, however, if there is only one item in the cart it will delete the correct one.

I also note that :

```
console.log("this is i" + e);
```

returns the correct value (the id of button in which it was clicked on)

Comment: I'd strongly advise changing your overall approach to the component, storing the indexes of clicked items in an array and having another array paralleling it with a disabled flag isn't best practice. Instead, store an array of objects which refer to the relevant `gameData` entry and have a disabled flag. We can't really help you based only on what's in the question above, but you're breaking two big rules of React state management: 1. You're directly modifying state (by using `splice` on an array in state), and...

Comment: ...2. You're setting state based on existing state, but not using the callback version of `setState`. State updates are asynchronous and can be batched, and so you can't do that. Use `this.setState(prevState => { /*...*/ })` and use the information from `prevState` instead. More: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

I personally find it stressful to use splice. Why not use filter instead so you'll have something like `this.state.clickedNum.filter(num => num.id !== e.target.id)`

```
removeClick = (e) => {
  id = e.target.id;
  let clickedNum = this.state.clickedNum.filter(num => num.id !==id);
  let isDisabled = this.state.filter(num => num.id !==id;


this.setState({
    clickedNum: clickedNum,
    isDisabled:isDisabled
  })
}
```

Comment: All due respect, this is about a quarter of an answer to the question. The quarter you provide is fine (it's not just stressful, it's **not allowed** to directly modify state), but...

Comment: You wouldn't be modifying the state directly, as you'll assign the return value of the filter to a variable before setting it to your state.

Comment: Right -- I was saying that using `splice` isn't just stressful, it's also wrong.